# How to import a component to UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

Sorry, I am new in React.js, just switched from Java and I can't understand how I shall show my map on UI. Just give me a hint

```
import React from "react";
import {Map, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';

class TestMap extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="GoogleMap">
        <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={14} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

GoogleApiWrapper({ 
  apiKey: ({api-key})
})(TestMap);

export {TestMap, GoogleApiWrapper};
```

here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {TestMap} from '../components/map/google/TestMap';

class Map extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          //???
        );
    }
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: How are you importing Map in the TestMap component?

Comment: Do you mean Google Map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a react component, render it as JSX

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TestMap } from '../components/map/google/TestMap';

class Map extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TestMap />
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

An aside, don't name your class component `Map` as there is already a Javascript `Map` object and this could be the cause for some major confusion and bugs.

**EDIT**

Your map is forever loading as you've exported the undecorated `TestMap`, i.e. it isn't decorated with the google api and props.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Map, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';

class TestMap extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="GoogleMap">
        <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={14} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// default export the decorated component so the api-key and google prop is processed and injected.
export default GoogleApiWrapper({ 
  apiKey: 'sLiGhTlyReDacTedApIkEy'
})(TestMap);
```

[image: Edit unruffled-mayer-d7s1w]

Comment: Thanks a lot!
But now I see "Loading map" and nothing more...
May be somebody have an experience with it and knows what can be issue with?

Comment: If you don't mind, can you load some of your code into a codesandbox that reproduces your issue and update your question with a link? Or better yet, mark this as resolved/answered and open a new question/issue. I would attempt a sandbox but I've not a googleAPI key at the ready.

Comment: I have tried yet but it seems that I shall study how it works first. Otherwise I will spend a lot of time for it to be done. So this is the API-key "AIzaSyCON2tfJRtD7jUtVGm5Ks-jWF2HQnaWhqM"

Comment: @RobertGurjiev Updated my answer. You just needed to export the component decorated by the google api wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return your component as JSX markup, [Introducing JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).

Also if you are new to react is suggest starting here, [Getting Started](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {TestMap} from '../components/map/google/TestMap';

class Map extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <TestMap />
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the component inside the return block.In your case `<TestMap />` inside the return of Map component.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I am not able to understand why are you adding one more abstraction of component over your Map component. You can directly use the TestMap component you have used in the first code snippet.
Anyway, You can directly return  from the Map Component.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {TestMap} from '../components/map/google/TestMap';

class Map extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <TestMap />
        );
    }
}

export default Map;
```

Answer (score 1):

Child Component

```
import React from "react";
import {Map, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';

class TestMap extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="GoogleMap">
        <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={14} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

GoogleApiWrapper({ 
  apiKey: ({api-key})
})(TestMap);

export default TestMap;
```

Parent Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {TestMap} from '../components/map/google/TestMap';

class Map extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <TestMap />
        );
    }
}

export default Map;
```